# Selecting Multiple links in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I was wondering if there is a way to select multiple links in Protractor when you do not know the amount of the links.  Currently I have a table which contains multiple (unknown in quantity) links that I have to select (click and move page) and then go through a series of processes for a test I am writing:

```
<table border="0" class="bodyTable">
<tbody><tr class="a">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th></tr>
        <tr class="b">
            <td><a href="Link3">Link1</a></td>
            <td>-</td></tr>
        <tr class="a">
            <td><a href="Link3">Link2</a></td>
            <td>-</td></tr>
        <tr class="b">
            <td><a href="Link3">Link3</a></td>
            <td>-</td></tr>
        <tr class="a">
            <td><a href="Link4">Link4</a></td>
        <td>-</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

The issue(s) is (I am using Protractor asynchronously as this is an non-Angular application) that since the pages that follow the link are mostly identical how do I select every element in an unknown list without re-writing a ridiculous amount of code.

My former methods were revolving around counting the tr's in the table and launching a series of loops but that is clumsy and, well, just bad code:

```
//something like this
elements(by.tagName('tr')).count().then(function(numberOfTRs) {
   for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfTRs; i++)
     elements(by.tagName('tr')).get(i);
});
```

However, the promises continue after the page is loaded and of course errors are produced.  There should be a way to wait (without using a browser.sleep(...)) however I am unsure of what to do.  Normally I would research this question but I don't even know what to search for (I'm guessing "idiot tying to use Protractor in a way other than it was designed" would turn up much).

Thanks in advance...

Editors Note:

An ideal function would work in this fashion

```
element(whatever).all(listsoflinks).someFunction(function (elementToUse, index) {
//...do stuff....
   //....return to page....
});
```

The closest thing I could find would be the "Each" function but it crashes out with error:

> ```
> Failed: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
> For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
> Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
> System info: host: 'BAHCND4397GQF', ip: '10.138.1.15', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_72'
> Driver info: driver.version: unknown
> ```
>
> So, obviously the function is "loosing" its footing when the page change happens

I put a counter (console.log) in the "each" function and it, of course, flys through as if its not a part of the promise...

Answer (score 1):

How about gathering the links into an array, loop over the array and navigate to every URL:

```
$$("table.bodyTable tr td a").getAttribute("href").then(function(links) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= links.length; i++) {
        browser.get(links[i]);
        // do smth
    }
});
```

Comment: This looks similar to what I had previously tried, the issue would be that the page would load and then instantly the next page in the loop would load (or the element, which is no longer there because the page has changed, would be selected), this might be solved with multiple browser implementations within the loop but that is just as clumsy as anything else (there must be a way of doing this without that)

Comment: @jsNoob it depends on what you have in the body of the loop. What exactly are you doing there?

Comment: Hold on @alecxe I am going to make an edit I think I have the answer to what I am trying to do

Comment: @jsNoob well, yeah, the first thought I had was "each" but since you follow links and navigate to a different page - all other links in the list immediately become "stale". You need to get the list of links as I've suggested and iterate over them. I'm pretty sure the approach I suggested should work in your case. What is this "do stuff" exactly?

Comment: I might just open another browser instance for each occurrence and handle it that way.  The other "do stuff" is actually clicking on yet more links and reading from the page (comparison and file i/o)